# InvalidOperationEception with serialization with EF Power Tools

Tags: serialization, invalidoperationexception, system.threading.executioncontext

When executing the below code: The block of code being executed is with the **stars**

public static class DbContextExtensions
{
public static async Task<List> SqlQueryAsync(this DbContext db, string sql, object[] parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class
{
if (parameters is null)
{
parameters = new object[] { };
}

```
    **if (typeof(T).GetProperties().Any())
    {
        return await db.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }**
    else
    {
        await db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, parameters, cancellationToken);
        return default;
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext&' of property 'Context' on type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SpiritWMSApiCore2.Models.Unitech_ASNInfo_BOLResult],SpiritWMSApiCore2.Models.SIRISContextProcedures+<Unitech_ASNInfo_BOLAsync>d__56]' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

I looked up with bing chat gpt and gives the following, but i still don't know how to resolve it...
System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext&' of property 'Context' on type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SpiritWMSApiCore2.Models.Unitech_ASNInfo_BOLResult],SpiritWMSApiCore2.Models.SIRISContextProcedures+<Unitech_ASNInfo_BOLAsync>d__56]' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

Comment: The error message you're seeing, `System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext&' of property 'Context' on type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SpiritWMSApiCore2.Models.Unitech_ASNInfo_BOLResult],SpiritWMSApiCore2.Models.SIRISContextProcedures+<Unitech_ASNInfo_BOLAsync>d__56]'

Comment: is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.`, is a .NET error that typically occurs when you're trying to serialize or deserialize a type that is not supported.

Comment: In your case, the type `System.Threading.ExecutionContext&` is causing the issue because it's a pointer type, a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

Comment: Here are a few potential solutions:

1. **Avoid serializing unsupported types**: If possible, avoid serializing types that are not supported. This includes pointer types, ref structs, and types with generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

2. **Replace generic parameters with specific types**: If your type contains generic parameters, replace them with specific types before serialization.

3. **Use a custom serializer**: If the built-in .NET serializers do not meet your needs, consider using a custom serializer that can handle more complex types.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was a missing `await` i.e. I was trying to serialise a `Task<something>` rather than a `something`. Serialising an uncompleted Task is obviously impossible

Comment: You saved my sitting device, mate.